# How to access Owner field using getDescribe().fields.getMap()

Tags: apex, trigger, sobject, describesobject, schema

I have a below code to access owner field from sObject.

```
Map <String, Schema.SObjectType > sObjects = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
Schema.SObjectType targetType = sObjects.get('Job_Application_Mirror__c');
Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> mtargetFields = targetType.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
mTargetFields.get('Owner');
System.debug('' + mTargetFields.get('Owner.Id'));
```

But I am getting null. Could anyone please help to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The API name for the Owner field is `OwnerId`. You will need to use the same here:

```
mTargetFields.get('OwnerId');
```

Comment: Thank You So much !!!.